# What is the best practice for Access Control in NodeJS microservices?

Tags: node.js

What is the best way for handle access control from web app to microservices and connection between microservices using NodeJS and Docker for containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most easy form is with http. You can linked the docker containers and send request with node-fetch.

=)